# Cannot Write to PHP Variable from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the MySQL statement to write to the variable $RegionString but I simply can't get it to work. I've looked at the obvious potential issues; the SQL works fine elsewhere if I'm trying to get it to echo and the database config script appears above this bit of code on the page.

```
<?php 

$Brand= $_GET["Brand"]; 
$ProductDescription= $_GET["ProductDescription"]; 

$RegionString = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT Region AS RegionString FROM WebDatabaseText WHERE (((WebDatabaseText.ProductDescription)='$ProductDescription') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Brand)='$Brand') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Language)='english') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Website)='secognac.com') AND Region Is Not Null )"),0);
?>
```

The page doesn't seem to break or go wrong with the code above - everything runs fine, but echo $RegionString just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Don't forget to use ```mysql_real_escape_string()``` and escape the content received from ```$_GET``` (for example: ```$Brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Brand']);```. Otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<?php 
$Brand= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Brand"]); 
$ProductDescription= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductDescription"]); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Region AS RegionString FROM WebDatabaseText WHERE (((WebDatabaseText.ProductDescription)='$ProductDescription') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Brand)='$Brand') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Language)='english') AND ((WebDatabaseText.Website)='secognac.com') AND Region Is Not Null )"),0);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$RegionString = $row[0];
echo $RegionString;
?>
```

And beware! If you are at this level, you still have time to get used to using PDO, not this obsolete and unsafe mysql_query thing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however that code doesn't seem to work and breaks all of the php on the rest of the page.

Comment: I don't know what else you have on that page, it's only modification of your snippet. You say config script appear? Are you sure this file has .php extension and not .html?

Comment: Other than the congic file, with the server, uname and password has just:

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$username);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

All of the rest of the php is just including other pages

Comment: To clarify, the config script doesn't appear (I just know where it is), and the file is definitely a .php file.

Running that code though just wipes the page out so that the browser sees a completely blank page.